# How to List<string>[] of List<string>[]

Tags: c#, list

I have a list like this:

```
List<string>[] lstGroups = new List<string>[]{new List<string>()};
```

and another one:

```
List<string>[] lstUsers = new List<string>[] { 
               new List<string>(),
               new List<string>(),
               new List<string>(),
               new List<string>(),
               new List<string>(),
               lstGroup };
```

This doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: "How can i do it?" how do you do what? what do you want to do?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I'm your father

Comment: what happens when you do that? what is your compiler error and/or runtime error?

Comment: are you trying to make a list of list of strings eg List<List<string>>?

Comment: `lstGroup` and `lstUsers` are arrays of lists, so you can't directly add lstGroup like that. You need to call `lstUsers.AddRange(lstGroup)`

Comment: I missed the error at first.  Didn't want to scroll to the right.

Comment: My code read an Active Directory and succeed to store in the list "lstUsers" all information i need. Each user can be in several groups and i want those groups to be stored in the list. So i try to create another list "lstGroups". How can i link them or store all groups for each user in the first one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lstUsers` is an array of lists.  When using the collection initializer you can add a bunch of lists.  Each item inside of the collection initializer needs to be of type `List<string>`.  `lstGroups` is of type `List<string>[]`.  It's an array of lists, not a list, so you can't include it as one item in the list.

If you want to add all of the items from `lstGroups` to `lstUsers` the easiest way to do so would probably be:

```
lstUsers = lstUsers.Concat(lstGroups).ToArray();
```

Comment: I wish to access the list like this : lstUsers[0][0] = User Name, lstUsers[0][1] = User Surname , ... , lstUsers[0][5] = list of all the groups where the user is member of. How can i have for each user in the list, the list of his groups. List of list in ArrayList ???

Comment: @user2241806 It sounds like you don't want to have a list at all.  It sounds like you want to create a new class that can have named properties for `Surname`, `Groups`, `Name`, etc., each with their own type.  Your variable isn't logically a collection, it's a custom object, so type it accordingly.